# $route.current return undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.when('/',{
    controller : 'secondController',
    activeTab : 'admin'
})

app.controller('secondController', ['$route', function($route){
    console.log($route.current.activeTab);
}])
```

Why am I getting undefined here? I can see the object when I do `console.log($route)`, that's strange.

Comment: Do you really mean `actiiveTab`? Probably just a typo.

Comment: @still_learning no that isn't the problem, i fixed the typo

Comment: So I guess `$route.current` is not `undefined` but `$route.current.activeTab` is. If `$route.current` was undefined, that line would crash instead of printing undefined. So the real problem is not `$route.current`, but its property `activeTab`. Where do you expect the property to come from?

Answer (score 2):

$route.current is available inside `$rootScope.$on '$locationChangeSuccess'` or in controller. But if you want to access current route (or expected current route) before route is resolved, e.g in `$rootScope.$on "$locationChangeStart"` or inside your run or config function then you can use `$route.routes[$location.path()]`.

but beware that routes with parameters will cause error `$route.routes[$location.path()]` which is important to know because the key of `$route.routes[key]` and `$location.path()` will mismatch. You can prove this to your self by console logging `$location.path()` and `$route.routes` inside run function.

If you have attached extra custom properties to your route then you can access them easily with `$route.routes[$location.path()]` like 
    `$route.routes[$location.path()].isLoginRequired`